# Auf den oder auf die Entscheidungen?

Tags: sentence-structure, grammatical-case

Ich schreibe gerade eine Arbeit und möchte meine Design-Entscheidungen begründen und versuche einen einleitenden Satz zu bauen.

Der Satz:

> Als erstes wird die graphische Oberfläche erläutert. Hier soll der Fokus **auf die Design-Entscheidungen** und deren Begründung liegen.

Ich bin mir unsicher, wie Ich den Satz am besten formuliere und ob **auf die Design-Entscheidungen** überhaupt richtig ist. Kann das so gesagt werden, oder sollte ich den Satz lieber komplett umschreiben?

Comment: Da Plural ganz klar ***den Entscheidungen***! Es ist nicht nötig, den Satz komplett umzuschreiben.

Comment: Und "Designentscheidungen" ein Wort.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Das Verb [*liegen*](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/liegen) mit der Präposition *auf* regiert den Dativ. Demnach muss es heißen:

> der Fokus liegt auf *den Entscheidungen*

Aber Vorsicht: Das ähnlich klingende Verb [*legen*](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/legen), das jedoch nicht den Zustand des Liegens, sondern den Vorgang des Legens beschreibt, regiert in Verbindung mit *auf* den Akkusativ:

> den Fokus auf *die Entscheidungen* legen

Ansonsten ist der besagte Satz aus der Fragestellung korrekt.

Comment: Was sollen die Abwertungen der drei korrekten Antworten hier?

Comment: Ah, guter Punkt auch die Akkusativversion einzubinden!

Comment: "Das Verb *liegen* regiert den Dativ" ist ungenau, vielmehr regiert *liegen auf* den Dativ - die Präposition ist wichtig!

Comment: @RHa, danke für den Hinweis. Ich habe es jetzt genauer geschrieben.

Comment: Ist das so? Liegen benötigt immer eine Ortsangabe und damit immer den Dativ. Es liegt auf/unter/neben/hinter/.... dem Tisch.

Answer (score 7):

<strike>Die Frage lautet `Worauf liegt der Fokus?` und erfordert daher den Dativ.</strike> In diesem Fall soll der Fokus `auf` etwas liegen. Dies ist - im weiteren Sinne - eine Beschreibung des Ortes (und nicht etwa einer Richtung) und erfordert daher den Dativ. Da es nicht nur um eine Entscheidung, sondern um mehrere geht, muss der korrekte Artikel also im Dativ Plural stehen, daher ist einzig

> Hier soll der Fokus auf **den** Design-Entscheidungen [...] liegen

korrekt

Comment: +1 auch für diese richtige Antwort.

Comment: Das *daher* im ersten Satz suggeriert, dass ein Grund genannt wurde. Das ist aber nicht der Fall. Es wird überhaupt nicht erklärt, warum die Frage *Worauf liegt der Fokus?* mit dem Dativ beantwortet werden soll.

Comment: Guter Punkt, ich habe es angepasst.

Answer (score 2):

Da [infinitzero](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/56399/36160) und [Björn Friedrich](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/56400/36160) die Frage nach dem Artikel vollständig beantwortet haben, meine Ergänzung zu

> sollte ich den Satz lieber komplett umschreiben?

Stiltechnisch - ein kleines bisschen.

Was sagt dieser Satz aus?

> Als erstes wird die graphische Oberfläche erläutert. Hier soll der Fokus auf die Design-Entscheidungen und deren Begründung liegen.

- Hier kommt jetzt eine Erläuterung - es geht also ins Detail.
- Es geht um die Design-Entscheidungen - wie und warum sie gefallen sind.
- *ich* als Autorin glaube es geht darum, aber ich habe keine Ahnung, ob es das tut

*=> Weniger Konjunktiv, mehr nüchtern "so isses".*

Den Duktus soweit beibehaltend:
<sup>ob "deren Begründung" oder "deren Begründungen" - ich habs vergessen</sup>

> Als erstes wird die graphische Oberfläche erläutert. Der Fokus liegt in diesem Kapitel/ Absatz/ Abschnitt auf den Design-Entscheidungen und deren Begründungen.

Den Duktus verändernd:

> Im ersten Kapitel/ Abschnitt/ Absatz wird die graphische Oberfläche erläutert. Der Fokus liegt auf den Design-Entscheidungen und ihren Begründungen.

- es wird mit "wird erläutert" klar gesagt, was getan wird. "ich erläutere" ist in einer Arbeit/ Aufsatz fehl am Platz.

> Im ersten Kapitel/ Abschnitt/ Absatz ist/ folgt die Erläuterung der graphischen Oberfläche. Der Fokus liegt auf den Design-Entscheidungen und ihren Begründungen.

- "die Erläuterung" ist ein unnötiges Verstecken des Verbs zur Frage "was wird da gemacht".

Answer (score 2):

Betrachte diese Verbpaare:

- legen - liegen

  > Erwin und Ilse **legen** die Bücher auf den Tisch, danach **liegen** die Bücher auf dem Tisch.
- stellen - stehen

  > Erwin und Ilse  **stellen** die Vasen auf den Tisch, danach **stehen** die Vasen auf dem Tisch.
- setzen - sitzen

  > Erwin und Ilse **setzen** sich an den Tisch, danach **sitzen** sie an dem Tisch.

Es gibt noch andere solcher Paare, aber manche von ihnen unterscheiden sich nicht in der Grundform sondern nur in der Beugung:

- hängen, hängte, gehängt - hängen, hing, gehangen

  > Der Direktor **hängte** das Bild an die Wand, danach **hing** das Bind an der Wand.

In den genannten Paaren ist das jeweils erste Verb ein *»kausatives Verb«* oder *»Verursacherverb«*. Das jeweils zweite ist das dazugehörige *resulatative Verb*. Beide Formen stammen jeweils von derselben etymologischen Wurzel ab.

Der Kausativ war früher eine grammatische Variante eines Verbs, mit der ausgedrückt werden sollte, dass das Objekt des Verbs vom Subjekt in einen neuen Zustand überführt wird, während das resultative Verb ausdrücken sollte, dass das Subjekt sich in diesem Zustand befindet. Eng verwandt mit dem *Kausativ* ist der  *Faktitiv*, beides wird von einigen Sprachwissenschaftlern unter dem Begriff *Kausativ* zusammengefasst.

Bei einigen Paaren hat einer der Partner einen Bedeutungswandel erfahren, so dass sie heute nicht mehr so exakt zueinander passen:

- schwemmen - schwimmen
- drängen - dringen
- zwängen - zwingen

Eine Gemeinsamkeit dieser Paare ist, dass das kausative Verb in seinem Präpositionalobjekt den Akkusativ sehen will, während das resultative Verb hier den Dativ verlangt. Diese Zuordnung erfolgt ganz analog zu den Fällen, die von den Verben der Bewegung verlangt werden und von jenen Verben, die ein Verharren an einem Ort benennen:

- Akkusativ = Bewegung, Veränderung

  > Ich lege das Buch in **den Kasten, die Kiste, das Gefäß**.
  >   Die Katze springt in **den Kasten, die Kiste, das Gefäß**.
- Dativ = unveränderlicher Ort, gleichbleibender Zustand

  > Das Buch liegt in **dem Kasten, der Kiste, dem Gefäß**.
  >   Die Katze schläft in **dem Kasten, der Kiste, dem Gefäß**.

Nachdem in dem Beispiel aus der Frage nicht der kausative Verb *legen* sondern das resultative Verb *liegen* verwendet wird, muss in dem Präpositionalobjekt der Dativ verwendet werden:

- männlich:

  > Der Fokus liegt auf **dem** Beschluss.
  >   Der Fokus liegt auf **den** Beschlüssen.
- sächlich:

  > Der Fokus liegt auf **dem** Mittel.
  >   Der Fokus liegt auf **den** Mitteln.
- weiblich:

  > Der Fokus liegt auf **der** Entscheidung.
  >   Der Fokus liegt auf **den** Entscheidungen.

Comment: Sehr gute Erläuterung (+1).

Comment: Kleiner Typo: Präpositiopnalobjekt (letzter Absatz)

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: Da du bereits mehr als 1000 Punkte hast, darfst (und sollst!) du solche Fehler auch in fremden Fragen und Antworten selbst ausbessern.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: ich unterlag der Annahme, dass das 6-Zeichen-Limit für jeden einzelnen Edit gilt. Und mehr fand ich nicht zum Editieren, daher dachte ich, nur ein Comment kann helfen.